# Как узнать текущий размер области вывода браузера?

Tags: javascript, экран

Как узнать текущий размер области вывода браузера без его GUI интерфейса учитывая кроссбраузерность?

[image: браузер]

Comment: А что такое по Вашему "область вывода браузера"? viewPort? Если да, то` window.innerWidth` и ` window.innerHeight`

Comment: @OlmerDale да это вьюпорт. это то что нужно. а я от экрана свойства пытался получить. сделайте ваш комментарий ответом, чтоб мой вопрос в воздухе не висел. я отмечу как его как верный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Та "область экрана", которая у Вас отмечена направляющими называется `view port`. Значения `view port` можно получить из глобальной области видимости -

```
window.innerWidth;
window.innerHeight;
```

Так же стоит заметить что существует очень похожая альтернатива в виде -

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth;
document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

`clientWidth` и `clientHeight` тоже указывают размеры `view port`, но с одним очень важным отличием, а именно с учетом полосы прокрутки. То есть если у нас ширина вьюпорта равна `1000px` и полоса прокрутки занимает `20px`, то `innerWidth` вернет значение `1000px`, в то время как `clientWidth` `980px`.